# Write Quick Sort in Haskell and need help to resolve the issue

Tags: haskell

I try to write a quick sort in Haskell and I knew there are many versions out there.

This one is pretty simple for Int type

```
quickSort1::[Int]->[Int]
quickSort1 [] = []
quickSort1 (x:xs) = [l | l <- xs, l < x] ++ [x] ++ [ r | r <- xs, r > x]
```

I can print on Main as following

```
print $ quickSort1 []   -- output []
print $ quickSort1 [2, 1] -- output [1, 2]
```

I modified the above quickSort1 to "more general" type with (Ord a) instead of Int

```
quickSort2::(Ord a)=>[a]->Maybe [a]
quickSort2 [] = Nothing 
quickSort2 (x:xs)  = Just $ [ l | l <- xs, l < x] ++ [x] ++ [ r | r <- xs, r > x]
```

On my Main, I can run

it works

```
print $ quickSort2 [2, 1] -- output [1, 2]
```

I got compiler error when I run following

```
print $ quickSort2 [] -- got error
```

Can anyone explain to me what is going on with my new version of quickSort2

Comment: "Can anyone explain to me what is going on with my new version of quickSort2" -- Nothing to be worried about. If you read the error again (and you should add the error to the question here and in such cases -- it makes things easier for everyone!), you will probably find out (I am guessing) it is basically saying that it doesn't know which type the empty list should have. If I am right, `print $ quickSort2 ([] :: [Int])` will not lead to an error, and your function will work just fine when you use it in the rest of your program, as long as you give things type signatures.

Comment: By the way, which version of GHC you are using? (Run `ghc --version` in the terminal if you don't know.)

Comment: on a side note - I hope you are aware that your implementation of quick-sort is incorrect `quicksort1 [10,9..1] /= [1..10]`, same goes for `quicksort1 [5,5,5]`. I am using ghc 8.0.1 and 7.10.3 and I cannot reproduce any error! for your second quicksort version

Comment: The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.3

Comment: 1) Your quickSort does not have any recursive calls. This is surely wrong. 2) Never say "I got an error" without posting the error! It might be useless to you but precious to potential answerers. 3) Why Maybe? I'd expect sorting to always returns a list...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you use a file `foo.hs` and in it

```
main = print $ quicksort []

quicksort = ... - as defined above in quickSort2
```

then you get two error messages when you `runghc foo.hs`

```
foo.hs:3:8: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus 11 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: print $ quicksort []
      In an equation for ‘main’: main = print $ quicksort []
```

one telling you that ghc cannot tell what `Show` instance to use and ghc 8 already tells you how to solve this:

add a type annotation (as @duplode already suggested)

```
main = print $ quicksort ([] :: [Int])
```

Quite similar but slightly different is the second error message

```
foo.hs:3:16: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘quicksort’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Ord a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Ord Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
        instance Ord Integer
          -- Defined in ‘integer-gmp-1.0.0.1:GHC.Integer.Type’
        instance Ord a => Ord (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus five instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘quicksort []’
      In the expression: print $ quicksort []
      In an equation for ‘main’: main = print $ quicksort []
```

Where in the first message the `print` function demanded a `Show` instance - here you promised the `quicksort` to supply a list of orderables - but did not say which to use, so GHC complains about what `Ord` to use.

Both messages are due to the fact that `[]` is too polymorphic it could be a list of anything - `[Int]` is good, but it could also be something like `[Int -> Bool]` which is neither `Show`able nor `Ord`erable.

You could as well supply `quicksort` with something weird like a

```
newtype HiddenInt = HI Int deriving (Ord) --but not Show
```

which would work for the `quicksort` function but not for `print`.

**Side Note**

Your `quicksort` functions need to be recursive in order to really be correct - as I pointed out in my comments - there is a logical problem in your algorithm - be sure to test your functions properly e.g.

```
import Data.List (sort)

main :: IO ()
main = do print $ "quicksort [10,9..1] == Just (sort [10,9..1]) is: "
           ++ show $ quicksort ([10,9..1]::Int]) == Just (sort ([10,9..1]::Int]))
          print $ "quicksort [5,5,5] == Just (sort [5,5,5]) is: "
           ++ show $ quicksort ([5,5,5] :: [Int]) == Just (sort ([5,5,5] :: [Int]))

quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Maybe [a]
quicksort = ...
```

or if you are interested take a look at [QuickCheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck) - which is a bit more advanced, but a step in the right direction for verifying your algorithms/functions work the way you expect them.